# how to usehtml2pdf to add horizontal line to pdf

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

i am working on PWA project which should generate pdf offline once the user enters data, so far i am using html2pdf library and i can produce the pdf but when i tried to add a line for footer its not display correctly. here is the screenshot how it displays on pdf [image]

and the code i am using to generate the pdf is below

```
    $(document).on("click", "#btnViewVisits", function(){
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/html/progressnotes.html", function(data) {
                  var opt = {
                    margin: 0.2,
                    filename: 'NewVisit.pdf',
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1.0 },
                    html2canvas: { scale: 2, bottom: 10 },
                    jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
                };
                html2pdf().from(data).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
                var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();

                
                for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                  pdf.setPage(i);
                  pdf.setFontSize(8);
                  pdf.line(0,pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.4, 315 , 0);
                  //pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 1, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.25);
                } 
              }).save();
            });
        });
```

i tried multiple values in pdf.line but it produces thick line and second its in a incline line. Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i finally able to solve this by changing few settings in the javascript, for anyone looking for solution, i am posting js method

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnViewVisits", function(){
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/html/progressnotes.html", function(data) {
                  var opt = {
                    margin: 5,
                    filename: 'NewVisit.pdf',
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1.0 },
                    html2canvas: { scale: 5 },
                    jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
                };
                html2pdf().from(data).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
                var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();

                
                for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                  pdf.setPage(i);
                  pdf.setFontSize(8);
                  pdf.setLineCap(2);
                  pdf.line(3,pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 20, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 , pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 20);
                  pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 25, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 10);
                } 
              }).save();
            });
        });
```